# Understanding Kohana ORM Relationships

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I can't seem to find one that really gives me a good understanding of how relationships work in Kohana's ORM Module.

I have a database with 5 tables:

```
approved_submissions
   -submission_id
   -contents

favorites
   -user_id
   -submission_id

ratings
   -user_id
   -submission_id
   -rating

users
   -user_id

votes
   -user_id
   -submission_id
   -vote
```

Right now, `favorites`,`ratings`, and `votes` have a Primary Key that consists of every column in the table, so as to prevent a user favoriting the same `submission_id` multiple times, a user voting on the same `submission_id` multiple times etc. I also believe these fields are set up using foreign keys that reference `approved_submissions` and `users` so as to prevent invalid data existing in the respective fields.

Using the DB module, I can access and update these tables no problem. I really feel as though ORM may offer a more powerful and accessible way to accomplish the same things using less code.

Can you demonstrate how I might update a user voting on a `submission_id`? A user removing a favorite `submission_id`? A user changing their rating on a particular `submission_id`?

Also, do I need to make changes to my database structure or is it okay the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [has_many_through](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through) relationships.

So to add a new submission, you'd do something like

```
 $user->add('submissions', $submission);
```

and to remove

```
 $user->remove('submissions', $submission);
```

You may want to consider restructuring your database table and key names so you don't end up doing a lot of configuration.